# Apps Script to Make a Copy of a Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

Just trying to make a simple script that makes a copy of a doc with a specified file ID and then opens that copy.

The following script makes the copy but doesn't actually open the document:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var fileId = e.parameters.fileId;  
    if(!fileId){
    //fileId = Google Doc Id
    fileId = '1eeNxjDEkA0P3XEq6xdM0R2wAcc6sNP5_7hU3_f4ViAA';
    } 
  var newId = DocsList.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy('File copied to my drive').getId(); 
  DocumentApp.openById(newId);
}
```

Can't figure out why. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check the Execution Log in the script editor.

Comment: Yes, but again, what I'm trying to do is open the document. All I am able to do it add the doc to my file list in Drive. Is there any way to actually open the document? Thanks.

Comment: I actually got the answer I needed from your question. I just needed to figure out how to copy a present doc:  DocsList.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy(...).getId();
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Opening a document" using Google-Apps-Script does not mean "open in your browser", it just gives you access to this document using any Google DocsList method, nothing else.

The best you could do to achieve what you are looking fo would be to throw a popup window showing your new file url that you could click to open (using an anchor widget from the UiApp service or a small HTML Ui).

This is a built in limitation of G-A-S and there is no way to go around it.